# IP addresses mapping in R

Tags: r

I have a df as below

```
A       IP       
Sam    1.0.0.9
```

and i want to map this IP's location given in the below df :
this is the sencond df containing all ip infos

```
IP1        IP2         Location
1.0.0.0    1.0.0.255   Queensland
```

I want the results to be like that

```
A       IP      Location  
Sam    1.0.0.9  Queensland
```

As 1.0.0.9 lies between 1.0.0.0  &  1.0.0.255 .
Any suggestions  ?

Comment: Surely this is not a code writing service web page. Have you tried anything?

Comment: `iptools` package has some great functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `iptools` to convert IPs to numeric,

```
df$Location <- ifelse(ip_to_numeric(df$IP) >= ip_to_numeric(df1$IP1) & ip_to_numeric(df$IP) <= ip_to_numeric(df1$IP2),df1$Location, "NA")
df
#    A      IP   Location
#1 Sam 1.0.0.9 Queensland
```

Comment: Tried this but getting an error called "Error: expecting a string vector" .

Comment: convert your `df$IP` and `df1$IP1`, `df1$IP2` to character